# Python while loop, print sequential odd numbers

Tags: python, while-loop

I'd appreciate some clarification on my python code.

The goal was to create a while loop in order to print every third sequential odd number between 2 and 19, inclusive. (The expected output is 7, 13, 19.)

After some trial and error, I got the following code to work.

```
i = 2
count = 0
while i <= 19:
    if (i%2 != 0):
        count += 1    
      
        if count == 3:
            print(i)
            count = 0
          
    i += 1
```

However, this is what I incorrectly expected to work:

```
i = 2
count = 0
while i <= 19:
    if (i%2 != 0):
        count += 1    
      
        if count == 3:
            print(i)
           
    i += 1
```

Why is line 9 (count = 0) needed in order for this to run properly? Why isn't line 2 enough?

Comment: did you try to add a print(count) to see how it behaves? When count == 3 it will print i. after that count will increase further and never be 3 again, since you only increase it, but never reset or decrement it.

Comment: If you didn't want to reset count to 0, you could test for `count % 3 == 0` rather than `count == 3`. Then you'll print when count is 3, 6, 9 etc.

Comment: I think your second code example would work if the condition checked that count was _divisible_ by 3, not _equal_ to 3.  As @GoldenDremora pointed out, your code always adds one to count, and never resets it back to zero, so it will only be _equal_ to three once, and never again after that.

Comment: Such numbers are far easier to generate using a `range` object and a `for` loop, so this kind of assignment irks me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try walking through the code and tracking what the variables `i` and `count` are at each iteration of the loop.

For example your first snippet will produce:

```py
i=2, count=0  # init
i=3, count=1
i=4, count=1
i=5, count=2
i=6, count=2
i=7, count=3  # 7 is printed, count is reset to 0
i=8, count=0
i=9, count=1
...
```

While the second will produce:

```py
i=2, count=0  # init
i=3, count=1
i=4, count=1
i=5, count=2
i=6, count=2
i=7, count=3  # 7 is printed, count is not reset
i=8, count=3
i=9, count=4
...
```

Notice in the second example that the count is always greater than or equal to 3 after printing the first value because it's never reduced or set back to 0. You could modify that line to `if count % 3 == 0` and not reset the count to 0 after printing as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **condition** that you specify in the whole loop is to print the value of that odd when your count is equal to 3 only. The reason why your code did not work is that when it comes to the next 3 odd numbers, your count will be added up to be 6, but your condition will met when it equal to 3 only. Therefore, the better way to fix this problem is to set a better condition to check for every 3 elements are counted. You should try :

```
# print when 3 odds are counted
if (count % 3 == 0):
      print(i)
```

This is better than always set count to be 0 at every loop. Just come up with the new condition